# How to stop my API from failing when new fields are added

Tags: .net, rest, entity-framework-6

I've build an API that receives from an 3thrd party supplier. They sometimes add new fields without warning which leads to errors in my API

The API uses the entity framework 6, the tables are in fact SQL Server views.

The code in the controller that receives the POST start with:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {                 
         var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

I suspect this is to strict. Is this necessary or wise to keep and test extra on type of errors.
Or can I remove this, but will this not result in eeror further along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the how you want the API to behave, i would need more context to provide better guidance.

1. You can keep the IsValid and have it strictly validate and throw errors (that you can handle).
2. Remove the IsValid if you know they are just gonna add fields that you do not care about and if you get a JSON in the POST, and it will de-serialize only the fields that you have in your model.
3. Create a custom deserializer/serializer that deals with all of this in whatever manner you want.